# Xcode CATransition looking as cube

Tags: objective-c, swift, ios8, xcode6

Is it possible to do a `CATransition` when swiping from left to right, e.g., that looks like a cube? That means that the text or ImageView or whatever animates in a way one thinks it is tilt by 90 degrees. Or maybe even that it is only tilt by 30 degrees. Some hint or code would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a solid open source project on github that does exactly that. The only thing you need is to have the nerves to embrace OpenGL.

https://github.com/MihaiDamian/Cube-transition-example

There is also the undocumented `CATransition.type` `@"cube"`. It looks pretty nice, but you will not be able to use this code for the app store.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try but isn't there a way to animate this kind of transition with CoreGraphics?

Comment: I meant CoreAnimation of course, that means the QuartzCore framework

Comment: Because looking at the code from Github I don't understand ANYTHING as I've never worked with OpenGL so far. I think it would take a lot of time to become familiar with it

Comment: You should still up-vote and/or accept this answer - it clearly solves the stated problem. -- Still, I am going to post a simpler answer.

Comment: Well ok then I'll wait for the simpler one before accepting this. I will clearly accept one of your answers then. But you can get your upvote already ;)